# printing a bot.event() to a specific discord channel

Tags: python

I'm wanting to have my bot send it's "I connected to discord" message to a specific discord channel. Here is my code currently

```
import random
import discord
import time 
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
TOKEN = ''

@bot.event
async def on_ready(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(774970601013379092)
    await channel.send(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello World")

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def shutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{bot.user.name} is shutting down. . .")
    await ctx.bot.logout()
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has disconnected from Discord!')


# c_sharp_challenges channel
@bot.command()
async def csharp(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(774683687018037249)
    await channel.send('Welcome To C#!')

# html_challenges channel
@bot.command()
async def html(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(774683714399371316) 
    await channel.send('Welcome To HTML!')

# java_challenges channel
@bot.command()
async def java(ctx):

    channel = bot.get_channel(774683618307342417)
    await channel.send('Welcome To Java!')

# java_script_challenges channel
@bot.command()
async def javascript(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(774683653728501761) 
    await channel.send('Welcome to Java Script!')

# python_challenges channel
@bot.command()
async def python(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(774683556077109258)
    await channel.send('Welcome To Python!')

    
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I can't seem to find anything on stackoverflow, or google in general, that can help me figure this out. it's in python, and I'm on ubuntu 20.04 if that matters

Answer (score 0):

That the bot sends an message to some channel that it is online. If you want to change the channel you just have to change the `channel_id` given in the `on_ready` function.

Comment: instead of it printing that the bot connected to the discord to the terminal, I want it to print that message to the specified channel ID that is already in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to notice that I had 00000 in for the channel ID

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")
    channel = bot.get_channel(774970601013379092)
    await channel.send("bot is online")
```